# Specify cipher on `openssl speed`

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to speed up benchmarks on `openssl speed`. Ideally, I would like to specify a cipher, e.g. RSA. Using the [openssl documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-speed.html), I've managed to speed things up by specifying the number of bytes i.e. `-bytes 4096` but this still takes forever to run.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation,

> [zero or more test algorithms]
> If any options are given, speed tests those algorithms, otherwise a pre-compiled grand selection is tested.

It can be a little tricky finding the exact name of the algorithms since they are case sensitive. Here are a few that works.

```
openssl speed aes
openssl speed rsa
# The bit length works with rsa, but I'm not sure how to add it to any others
openssl speed rsa2048
openssl speed des
openssl speed camellia
openssl speed ecdsa
openssl speed ecdh
```